# Building an array while looping

Tags: matlab, arrays

I have a for loop that loops over one array...

```
for i=1:length(myArray)
```

In this loop, I want to do check on the value of myArray and add it to another array myArray2 if it meets certain conditions. I looked through the MATLAB docs, but couldn't find anything on creating arrays without declaring all their values on initialization or reading data into them in one shot.

Many thanks!

Comment: You will probably find the following links of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680557/optimizing-extraction-of-data-from-a-matlab-matrix, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132092/what-are-your-favourite-matlab-octave-programming-tricks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450322/matlab-excluding-data-outside-1-standard-deviation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202641/how-do-i-compare-all-elements-of-two-arrays-in-matlab

Comment: let me add this one to the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something more complicated than

```
myArray = [1 2 3 4 5];
myArray2 = myArray(myArray > 3);
```

The easiest (but slowest) way to do what you're asking is something like

```
myArray2 = [];
for x = myArray
    if CheckCondition(x) == 1
        myArray2 = [myArray2 x]; %# grows myArray2, which is slow
    end;
end;
```

You can sort of optimize this with something like

```
myArray2 = NaN(size(myArray));
ctr = 0;
for x = myArray
    if CheckCondition(x) == 1
        ctr = ctr + 1;
        myArray2(ctr) = xx;
    end;
end;
myArray2 = myArray2(1:ctr); %# drop the NaNs
```

You might also want to look into [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html).

Comment: Why you have used NaNs, can I use zeros or ones?

Comment: @dexterdev you can, yes.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, the way to do what you're describing is like mtrw said in the first example.

Let's say `data = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`, and you want to get only the even numbers.

```
select = mod(data,2)==0; % This will give a binary mask as [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1].
```

If you do `data2=data(select)`, it will give you `[2 4 6 8 10]`.

Of course, the shorter way to do this is as mrtw had in example 1:

```
data2=data(some_criteria);
```

Comment: Just a small precission. The mask must be an array of logicals, it seems. I tested with select=[0 1 0 1...] and got an error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals". Then I tried with select=[false true false true...] and it worked as expected.