# Constructing a matrix in matlab from values generated by for loop

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Matlab - building an array while looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480933/matlab-building-an-array-while-looping)
>   [Matrix of unknown length in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab)

How do you put all of the "a" values together to form a vector?

```
for i=1:3
    a=2+i
end
```

Also this is maybe a style question but when do you put a semicolon after the end in a for loop such as the one above, also is it proper to put a semicolon after the first line?

Comment: I guess this only a simplified example and you actually more in your for-loop. If not, you can vectorize everything to a one-liner: `a = 2 + (1:3);`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480933/matlab-building-an-array-while-looping, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

You need to index into `a`, like this:

```
for ii=1:3
  a(ii) = 2+ii;
end
```

I prefer to use `ii` as a loop variable to avoid clashing with MATLAB's built-in `i`. You should also pre-allocate `a` if you know the size before the start of the loop, like so:

```
N = 100;
a = zeros(1,N);
for ii=1:N
  a(ii) = 2 + ii; 
end
```

Personally, I never put any punctuation after the `for ii=1:3` part, except when writing a one-liner `FOR` loop, like so:

```
for ii=1:N, a(ii) = 2 + ii; end
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can construct this more efficiently as such:

```
a=1:3;
a=a+2;
```

The first line assigns `a` to be the vector `(1,2,3)`, the 2nd line adds `2` to every element.

"Efficiency" doesn't matter much in such a small vector, but in general you'll get much better mileage out of matlab if you get used to thinking more like this.