# Matlab: how to implement a dynamic vector

Tags: matlab, dynamic, vector, language-implementation

I am refering to an example like this 
I have a function to analize the elements of a vector, 'input'. If these elements have a special property I store their values in a vector, 'output'.
The problem is that at the begging I don´t know the number of elements it will need to store in 'output'so I don´t know its size.
I have a loop, inside I go around the vector, 'input' through an index. When I consider special some element of this vector capture the values of 'input' and It  be stored in a vector 'ouput' through a sentence like this:

```
For i=1:N %Where N denotes the number of elements of 'input'
...
output(j) = input(i);
...
end
```

The problem is that I get an Error if I don´t previously "declare" 'output'. I don´t like to "declare" 'output' before reach the loop as output = input, because it store values from input in which I am not interested and I should think some way to remove all values I stored it that don´t are relevant to me.
Does anyone illuminate me about this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: You will find these useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480933/matlab-building-an-array-while-looping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How complicated is the logic in the for loop?

If it's simple, something like this would work:

```
output = input ( logic==true )
```

Alternatively, if the logic is complicated and you're dealing with big vectors, I would preallocate a vector that stores whether to save an element or not.  Here is some example code:

```
N = length(input); %Where N denotes the number of elements of 'input'
saveInput = zeros(1,N);  % create a vector of 0s
for i=1:N
    ...
    if (input meets criteria)
        saveInput(i) = 1;
    end
end
output = input( saveInput==1 ); %only save elements worth saving
```

Answer (score 2):

The trivial solution is:

```
% if input(i) meets your conditions
output = [output; input(i)]
```

Though I don't know if this has good performance or not

Comment: You need to add `output = [];` at the beginning.  And the performance is terrible.

Comment: So it's a good solution when you don't care about performance :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `N` is not too big so that it would cause you memory problems, you can pre-assign `output` to a vector of the same size as `input`, and remove all useless elements at the end of the loop.

```
output = NaN(N,1);
for i=1:N
...
output(i) = input(i);
...
end
output(isnan(output)) = [];
```

There are two alternatives

If `output` would be too big if it was assigned the size of `N`, or if you didn't know the upper limit of the size of `output`, you can do the following

```
lengthOutput = 100;
output = NaN(lengthOutput,1);
counter = 1;
for i=1:N
   ...
   output(counter) = input(i);
   counter = counter + 1;
   if counter > lengthOutput
       %# append output if necessary by doubling its size
       output = [output;NaN(lengthOutput,1)];
       lengthOutput = length(output);
   end
end
%# remove unused entries
output(counter:end) = [];
```

Finally, if N is small, it is perfectly fine to call

```
output = [];
for i=1:N
   ...
   output = [output;input(i)];
   ...
end
```

Note that performance degrades dramatically if N becomes large (say >1000).